# Merge milestone, motorola-milestone

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

Same device

[milestone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milestone)
[motorola-milestone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-milestone)